# Не работает подключение api 3.0

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Пробую выполнить подключение как описано в [инструкции](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/3.0/quick-start/index.html?from=jsapi#conditions) выдает код ошибки 400 (
На версии 2.1 все работает нормально. Может кто-то сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Без кода ваш вопрос не даст вам помочь. Вы даже не написали, привязали ли api-ключ к домену, на котором пытаетесь запустить код. А без привязки оно работать точно не будет.